# How to refrence a URP Bloom effects intensity value in script in Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp, bloom

I want to **change the intensity value of a bloom effect in a script** in unity2D using Universal Render Pipeline.

I tried looking in the URP Bloom manuals and even unitys bloom manuals and found no result, i watched some YT tutorials and none explained how to refrence only the intensity value of a Bloom effect in script. Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First obtain a reference to the `PostProcessVolume`.

```
var volume = GetComponent<PostProcessVolume>();
```

Then try to get the bloom settings from the profile.

```
Bloom bloom;
volume.profile.TryGetSettings(out bloom);
```

Now you can modify the bloom properties.

```
bloom.intensity.value = 0.5f;
```

For URP

namespaces

```
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;
```

Volume

```
var volume = GetComponent<Volume>();
```

Bloom component

```
volume.profile.TryGet(out Bloom bloom);
```

Intensity

```
bloom.intensity.value = 40;
```

IMPORTANT NOTE from the author of the question: for this problem the error was due to the GetComponent function trying to get the volume from itself while the volume was in a different game object, to solve this problem the final code on that line was:

```
var volume = objectWithVolume.GetComponent<Volume>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tired doing the exact steps and got an error, i figured out that i forgot to import UnityEngine.Rendering and UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing, but even after importing it gives me an error for object not set for instance of an object in line 36 which was: volume.profile.TryGetSettings(out bloom); ..., could you please explain how i can get a refrence through the inspector or in some other way. But I apriciate the help a lot as it cleared some stuff out for me.

Comment: I added another section in my answer that refers to post processing in URP.  With URP the namespaces and volume component changed.  Let me know if this approach works for you.

Comment: After doing the URP steps i got the exact same problem but this time after setting the volume as public it allowed me to drag it in the field manually in the inspector, but after starting it depopulates the field to None and throws out the same error. Basicaly i think that the problem is not being able to get refrence to the volume correctly, so if you have any other ideas on how i could do it i would greatly apriciate them and try them out.

Comment: I found a solution to my own problem:

so everything you told me was correct but the problem was that the volume component was not obtained because i was trying to acess it from itself while the volume was in a different game object. I found the problem of a missing game object with some help of the Phind website AI. So thanks alot for the help, the problem ended up being small and it made me feel very stupid for not seeing it earlier but at very last the code now works with your and Phinds help